# What's the most efficient way to search words in this kind of file by Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have a file like:

```
Fruit.Store={
    #blabla
    "customer-id:12345,item:store/apple" = 10;   #blabla
    "customer-id:23456,item:store/banana" = 10;   #blabla
    "customer-id:23456,item:store/watermelon" = 10;
    #blabla
    "customer-id:67890,item:store/watermelon" = 10;
}
```

Except the comments, each line has the same format: customer-id and item:store/ are fixed, and customer-id is a 5-digit number. There are about 1000 unique lines in the file. When "12345" and "apple" are input, the first line should be returned. What's the most efficient way to solve this problem by Ruby? Thank you!

Comment: Man, please show us your research effort. Looks like you didn't try it yet on your own. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def lookup(input, id, fruit)
  IO.foreach(input).detect do |line|
    line =~ %r|^\p{Space}*customer-id:#{id},item:store/#{fruit}|
  end
end
lookup("/path/to/file", 12345, 'apple')
#⇒ "    \"customer-id:12345,item:store/apple\" = 10;   #blabla\n"
```

Comment: You could use `%r|^[ \t]*"customer...` to ensure that you are not capturing a commented-out line.

Comment: And I think you can shorten the code to `IO.foreach(input).find { |line| line =~ pattern }`

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, I have tried it and added a puts ahead of line =~, but nothing returned

Answer (score 1):

> What's the most efficient way to solve this problem by Ruby?

(*Assuming you can load the whole dataset in memory at once and keep it there.*)

On load, transform your file into a hash of this shape.

```
data = {
  [12345, 'apple'] => 10,
  [23456, 'banana'] => 10,
  ...
}
```

Then you just do this:

```
data[[12345, 'apple']] # => 10 or nil (if not found)
```

This gives you O(1) lookups. You can't get more efficient than this.

If you want to work on the file directly, then you can read file line-by-line and try detect matching line, as shown in @mudasobwa's answer. The lookups in that case are much less efficient, but, on the other hand, it requires no preprocessing. So if you just want to do one lookup, that might be more efficient overall.

Comment: _"But that is much less efficient"_ – depends on whether you have to / can do multiple lookups or just a single one (per script invocation).

Comment: @Stefan: agreed. Reworded.